# Debug IIS hosted node.js app with MS Code

Tags: node.js

I have inherited a node.js app that is hosted in IIS and uses Windows Authentication. I am using MS Code as the IDE.

I can step thorough the code when it is hosted with the express server (i.e. pressing F5), but I need to be able to step through the code when it is hosted in IIS. I am testing functionality specific to Windows Authentication.

Anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you can't get access to the Windows Authentication endpoint (or use LDAP or a dev credentials for Windows Authentication), then unfortunately the best thing you can do would be to add verbose logging into the code.

Comment: Windows auth is working and I can determine the user name of the user making a request. But the code sets different permissions based on values retrieved from a database. I want to be able to step through the code and watch some variables. I can't seem to do that with an IIS hosted node.js app.

Comment: Have you looked at [this Article?](https://medium.com/@bogac/remote-debugging-node-js-apps-on-iis-with-iisnode-setup-for-express-4-part-2-ntvs-5eabe99d2ae9)

Comment: I was just reading it!  :-)  I am going to give it a try, but I'm concerned that the method described is specific to Azure.  I will report back.